# Xamarin won't build due to missing .dll.mdb files

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin

Currently working on a Xamarin.Mac solution that suddenly won't build due to two of the  referenced projects missing their '[projectName].dll.mdb' (mono debugging symbols) file.

Aren't these automatically generated by Xamarin Studio?  Is there any way to manually generate these files?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: post the whole build output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just solved this for myself. I think one of my projects was renamed and was built under that name. When I did a build it saw that project was up to date. I did a Clean All and then Build and everything worked. Good Luck.